# Python rolling assignment based on a regex match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to do a rolling assignment based on a regex match. I have a dataframe of keys (keys_df) and dataframe of new data coming in (new_df). 
For each name in the new_df if the name contains any of the substrings in the `keys_df.contains` column, then assign the `parent_id` and `parent_name` to that new record. If there is no match then leave null.

From the two data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

keys_df = pd.DataFrame([ ["steve"  , "2266", "Steve, Inc"], 
                    ["edward" , "3377", "Ed, Inc"],
                    ["Juan"   , "4488", "Juan, Inc"],
                    ["Pedro"  , "5599", "Pedro, Inc"]], 
                    columns=["contains", "parent_id", "parent_name"])

new_df = pd.DataFrame([ [ "9845" , "steve (bikes) qc", None,None],
            [ "9846" , "mark inc",None,None],
            [ "9847" , "young steve",None,None],
            [ "9845" , "Juan 22",None,None],
            [ "9845" , "Zak",None,None]],
            columns=["id", "name", "parent_name", "parent_id"])
```

I would like the output to look something like:

```
  id            name         parent_id    parent_name
"9845"  "steve (bikes) qc"      "2266"   "Steve, Inc" 
"9846"          "mark inc"       None          None
"9847"       "young steve"      "2266"   "Steve, Inc"
"9845"           "Juan 22"      "4488"    "Juan, Inc"
"9845"               "Zak"       None          None
```

There is also a question of efficiency here. The output dataframe will be appended onto a SQLite table. So if there is a way to do this in SQLite over pandas it would be appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas` [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
pat = '('+'|'.join(keys_df.contains)+')'
new_df['contains'] = new_df.name.str.extract(pat)
df = new_df.loc[:,['id','name','contains']].merge(keys_df,on='contains',how='left')
df.drop('contains',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

---

```
print(df)

     id              name parent_id parent_name
0  9845  steve (bikes) qc      2266  Steve, Inc
1  9846          mark inc       NaN         NaN
2  9847       young steve      2266  Steve, Inc
3  9845           Juan 22      4488   Juan, Inc
4  9845               Zak       NaN         NaN
```

**Explanation :**

```
print(new_df.name.str.extract(pat))
       0
0  steve
1    NaN
2  steve
3   Juan
4    NaN
```

Comment: Beautifully done. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @RandomForester Glad to help.

Comment: @RandomForester Check the new update even faster and simpler.